# Is there a syntax-directed editor generator, similar to XText, for Swing?

Tags: swing, syntax-highlighting, text-editor, grammar

I would like to include a syntax-directed editor, as a kind of super-rich edit box, in a Swing application. Is there anything that can help generate this from a grammar, in a similar way to XText for Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tow options :

- using [netbeans plugins](http://wiki.netbeans.org/How_to_create_support_for_a_new_language)
- using custom components like [RSyntaxTextArea](http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/)